# How can I edit the ajustable style of the TikZ-circuits.ee.IEC resistor?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib, circuits

Good Evening!

I want to draw some X-dependent resistor (like temperature-dependent, as shown in the picture [there are some parts in red at this moment]).

I have a solution, but I do not think, this is the right way.

Is there a possibility, to edit the [adjustable style](http://code.google.com/p/graph-theory-algorithms-book/source/browse/style/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/circuits/tikzlibrarycircuits.ee.code.tex?r=dfd30bed8927bf4a5b50b6bf694708e7a388d092) in a simple setting, to get the form as wished?
For example, I can kill its arrowhead with the setting:

```
\tikzset{NoArrowhead/.style={annotation arrow/.style = {> = none}}}
```

Can I add the tiny red line and a textsymbol in a similar way?

BTW: The letter 'vartheta' has not to be a fix symbol, because there could be some other dependences, like voltage-dependence for example, so we need the symbol 'V'

*Thank you for reading and for your interest!*

[image]

OK, here is my Code - say, what you mean.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

%% temp adjustable %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{
temp adjustable/.style={
append after command={%
%NEW:
(-2.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) edge[line to, red]
(-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) 
%OLD:
(-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) edge[line to] (1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit)
%NEW
node[red] () at (-0.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) {$\vartheta$}
}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%===========
\begin{document}
%===========
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC, font=\sffamily\footnotesize]

\draw (3,0) to  [resistor= {temp adjustable}] (5,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
%===========
\end{document}
%===========
```

Comment: The is no one right way!  There are other ways, but this is fairly simple and effective.

Comment: Mmhh, but so test my "solution", she is not very consistent, due to 'infotexts' and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, due to the comment from John Kormylo, I apreciate;
so let me present you my solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LowUpDep %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{dependent/.style={annotation arrow/.style = {>=}}}
%
%
%LowDep %%%%%
\tikzset{LowDep/.style args={#1}{
append after command={%
\bgroup
[current point is local=true]
[every LowDep/.try]
[annotation arrow,-]
(-2.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) edge[line to]
(-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) node[xshift=3.0\tikzcircuitssizeunit]{#1}
\egroup%
}},
%
LowDep'/.style args={#1}{
append after command={%
\bgroup
[current point is local=true, yscale=-1]
[every LowDep/.try]
[annotation arrow,-]
(-2.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) edge[line to]
(-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) node[xshift=3.0\tikzcircuitssizeunit]{#1}
\egroup%
}}
}
%
%
%
%UpDep %%%%%
\tikzset{UpDep/.style args={#1}{
append after command={%
\bgroup
[current point is local=true]
[every UpDep/.try]
[annotation arrow,-]
%
(2.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit)  edge[line to]
(1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) node[xshift=-3.0\tikzcircuitssizeunit]{#1}
\egroup%
}},
%
UpDep'/.style args={#1}{
append after command={%
\bgroup
[current point is local=true, yscale=-1]
[every UpDep/.try]
[annotation arrow,-]
%
(2.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit)  edge[line to]
(1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) node[xshift=-3.0\tikzcircuitssizeunit]{#1}
\egroup%
}}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%===========
\begin{document}
%===========

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC, font=\sffamily\footnotesize]

%
\draw (0,0) to  [resistor={LowDep={foo}, UpDep={bar}, adjustable={
info={Testtext}, info'={Testtext}
}}, dependent] (2,0);

\draw (0,-2) to  [resistor={LowDep={foo}, adjustable}, dependent] (2,-2);

\draw (0,-4) to  [resistor={UpDep={bar}, adjustable}, dependent] (2,-4);


%
\draw (3,0) to  [resistor={LowDep'={foo}, UpDep'={bar}, adjustable'={
info={Testtext}, info'={Testtext }
}}, dependent] (5,0);

\draw (3,-2) to  [resistor={LowDep'={foo}, adjustable'}, dependent] (5,-2);

\draw (3,-4) to  [resistor={UpDep'={bar}, adjustable'}, dependent] (5,-4);

%%
\draw (0,-6) to  [capacitor={LowDep={foo}, UpDep={bar}, adjustable}, dependent] (2,-6);

\draw (3,-6) to  [diode={LowDep={foo}, UpDep={bar}, adjustable}, dependent] (5,-6);

\end{tikzpicture}
%===========
\end{document}
%===========
```

Comment: So do you need any help now?

Comment: No, I think it is ok.  What do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make the `\vartheta` adjustable, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

%create new parameter
\tikzset{adj var/.initial={\vartheta}}

%% temp adjustable %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{
temp adjustable/.style={
append after command={%
%NEW:
(-2.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) edge[line to, red]
(-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) 
%OLD:
(-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) edge[line to] (1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit)
%NEW
node[red] () at (-0.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) {$\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/adj var}$}
}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%===========
\begin{document}
%===========
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC, font=\sffamily\footnotesize]

\draw (0,0) to  [resistor= {temp adjustable}, adj var=V] (2,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
%===========
\end{document}
%===========
```

[image: adj var]

Comment: Hey, ah ok! Have a look on my answer. So how I wrote it, you could take text, what ever you want on to lower and upper dependence ;)